# Check multiple columns for value, replace with NA if not found in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame like this:

```
#df1
ID     a1      a2     a3      b1      b2      b3     Date    Name
3xy    NA      NA     NA     Ben      Bob     Alex   12/3    Bob
4lm    John    Bill   Sue    NA       NA      NA     12/5    Mark
```

I want those in the "name" column to be replaced by NA if they don't appear in any of the a1 through b3 columns in their row, like this:

```
ID     a1      a2     a3      b1      b2      b3     Date    Name
3xy    NA      NA     NA     Ben      Bob     Alex   12/3    Bob
4lm    John    Bill   Sue    NA       NA      NA     12/5    NA
```

I can't figure out why what's below doesn't work:

```
df1$Name <- with(df1, ifelse(Name %in% df1[2:7], Name, NA))
```

or

```
df1$Name[!(df1$Name %in% df1[2:7])] <- NA
```

Both statements replace the entire "Name" column with NA, failing to preserve the names that appear in columns a1 through b3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution using `apply` and `ifelse`:

```
df1$Name <- apply(df1, 1, function(x) ifelse(x[9] %in% x[2:7], x[9], NA))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this:

```
df1$Name[!(df1$Name %in% t(df1[, 2:7]))] <- NA
```

Notice, the `,` before the `2:7` so that the appropriate columns are selected and the `t()` which transposes these columns to make the `%in%` work on the vectors.

This solution is quite close to your second approach.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `rowSums` to assign the value of 'Name' column to NA if there is no TRUE elements in any of the columns for each row

```
df1$Name[!rowSums(t(t(df1[2:7] ) == df1$Name), na.rm = TRUE)] <- NA
```